# How to know the path of a native library that JVM loaded?

Tags: java

Assume a Java source code uses `System.loadLibrary("lib-name")` to load a library `lib-name`. Further, assume that multiple copies of `lib-name` exist throughout the system.

Question: is there a way to know the **path** of the `lib-name` that the jvm loaded? I'm looking for something like `-verbose:class`.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the first directory in [System] property `java.library.path` that contains _lib_name_?

Comment: Are you trying to know within the application or for information on another running vm, and which OS?

Comment: @DuncG system is Linux. No, not within the application. Assume this: someone gave me a jar file that loads a lib-name. Question: can I know the path where the jvm would picked up the library lib-name during startup or runtime? (Assume I have the library in my system at multiple locations). I know I can force it to pick a specific one via java.library.path, which is not my question. And don't tell me that I need to look into my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix style OS the fully qualified paths for libraries should be visible in `lsof | grep {yourjvmpid}`.

The `lsof` output will print a lot of information on open file handles - it is also very helpful to track bad resource handling in application code - and with suitable additional `| grep` you should narrow down the information for various `.so` files or the library path you are searching for.

Use `jps` or `ps -ef` to track down the appropriate pid.

Comment: thanks! exactly what I needed.